# In Qt - How to see start of text in a narrow combo box?

Tags: qt, combobox

I have a `QComboBox` which I have populated with `addItem()` repeatedly, and then selected an item with `setCurrentIndex()`.  The trouble is that some of the text is wider than the width of the box and it shows the text moved to the left so the right-hand-side is visible.  I want the text in the edit box to be positioned the same as the text in the drop-down box (so the start of text is visible on the left-hand-side, and any oversized text unseen on the right).

Some suggested reasoning:  I think it may be trying to ensure the cursor is visible, after leaving the cursor at the end.  But I have tried using `setCursorPosition(1)` but there is no such function in `QComboBox`.